# error reading a text file in octave

Tags: matlab, octave, file-read

I have a text file named `xMat.txt` which has 200 space separated elements in one line and some 767 lines.

This is how `xMat.txt` looks.

```
386.0 386.0 388.0 394.0 402.0 413.0 ... .0 800.0 799.0 796
801.0 799.0 799.0 802.0 802.0 80 ... 399.0 397.0 394.0 391
.
.
.
```

When I try to read the file in octave using `X = dlmread('xMat.txt',' ')` I get a matrix of size `767 X 610`. I am expecting a matrix of size `767 X 200` since there are 200 elements in one row. How can I solve this problem?

Edit - [This is my file](https://bpaste.net/show/96cf21aa21b8)

Comment: Did you investigate the content of `X`? This will give you some hints. I would guess you have a lot of additional spaces in your file.

Comment: I cheked, no additional spaces.

Comment: What is in `X(1,2)`? Side note : You'd have a lot more control on the way you import your file using `textscan`

Comment: @raptor96: what does your resulting X consist of or look like? As said by Bernhard, if you have by accident additional spaces in your xMat.txt file, it will add additional columns with zeroes in X, which may explain why you have more columns.

Comment: There are lots of additional zeros after 200th column in X, how did this add up?

Comment: Check in your txt file if after your last column there is directly an enter (which should be the case), or if there are lots of trailing spaces.

Comment: there is only one trailing space and an enter. Should this cause the problem?

Comment: Can you upload the file (bpaste.net, dropbox, github...) and add a link here so we can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your uploaded file https://bpaste.net/raw/96cf21aa21b8 has incosistent number of columns per row.

```
$ awk "{print NF}" tmp | sort | uniq -c
      2 200
    754 201
      1 206
      1 217
      1 223
      1 234
      1 237
      1 238
      1 269
      1 273
      1 390
      1 420
      1 610
```

So the most rows have 201 columns but one has 420 columns and one even has 610 columns. This is the reason you get a 767x610 matrix from dlmread.

Lets look which lines have more than 201 columns:

```
$ awk "{if (NF>201) print NR, NF}" tmp
68 217
580 206
613 390
615 234
657 273
676 610
679 237
720 269
722 238
743 223
762 420
```

The first coloumn shows the line number, the second number of columns.
So your line with 610 columns is line number 676. I aslo printed line 676:

[image: line 676]

so you see it really contains data, no multiple spaces which are filles with zeros.